# Not able to covert an Interface to struct based on condition in Golang

Tags: go, struct, interface

I have two structs here as added below, I am trying to create one generic function in which I'm passing the struct name as a string. I recently started working on Go.

```
type UserDetail struct {
    FirstName string 
    LastName  string 
    Email     string 
    User      int
    ReportsTo int
}

type Matter struct {
    ID        int 
    Name      string 
    Active    bool 
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    UserID    int
}
```

Function snippet is added below

```
func Testing(model string) {
    var temp interface{}
    if model == "UserDetail" {
        fmt.Println("Enterr...")
        temp = UserDetail{}
    }
    temp.FirstName = "Dev"
    temp.Email = "dev@gmail.com"
    fmt.Println(temp) // {"", "", "", 0, 0}
}
```

I'm calling the function as `Testing("UserDetail")`

I'm calling the function with struct name as a string and in the function definition, based on the struct name I'm creating a desired struct instance by converting the empty interface. After creating the empty struct instance, if I'm trying to add any filed values to it, and try to print the variable it is giving me an error saying:

```
prog.go:33:6: temp.FirstName undefined (type I is interface with no methods)
prog.go:34:6: temp.Email undefined (type I is interface with no methods)
```

And if I'm not updating the variable fields, it is printing the variable with default values. My main motivation is to convert the interface into struct based on condition and use the converted variable through out the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the underlying concrete value from the interface before finally able to modify it's property.

In golang, there is something called [type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15), it's used to get concrete value from interface variable.

> A type assertion provides access to an interface value's underlying concrete value.

Usage example:

```
tempConcreteValue := temp.(UserDetail)
tempConcreteValue.FirstName = "Dev"
tempConcreteValue.Email = "dev@gmail.com"

fmt.Println(tempConcreteValue) // {"", "", "", 0, 0}
```

As we can see on the code above, the `.(UserDetail)` at the end of `temp` will return the concrete value of interface `temp`, in `UserDetail` type.

Comment: I need this tempConcreteValue to be declared in `if` condition and then it must be accessible outside the if block.  I need this function to be a generic one.

Comment: you can make the `Testing()` function returns `interface{}` data. but if you want the `Testing()` to return a data with dynamic type (not wrapped in `interface{}`), like sometimes it'll return value in `UserDetail`, or `SomethingDetail`, or `AnotherStruct`; then it's impossible. go is static typing language, the only thing to achieve dynamic return value is through `interface{}` type.

Comment: But I am anyway returning the interface in my actual code (This is not actual code). The objective is that users would define their own structs and call a function similar to the `Testing` and I would get the data from the correct table in a database and then return the interface filled with data. This data pulling function replicated as `Testing` should be able to work irrespective of struct.

Answer (score 0):

Go never works like that. Because go is statically typed. Hence in compile time, it cant understand `temp.FirstName = "Dev"`, because temp is just an interface{}( which can hold any value).

But a number of features make it "appear" to be (at least somewhat) dynamically typed. You can either choose the answer by @xpare or declare a separate variable for each structs.

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to set field values to the `UserDetail` struct that you assigned to the `interface{} temp`. But the field were belong to the `UserDetail` struct, not to the `temp interface{}`. That's why 1st you need to get the `UserDetail` struct from the `interface{}` and set the expected field values. Also use pointer sign to ensure that the values are set to the original `UserDetail` struct. And then print the `temp interface{}`. Go will print the original values. So use like this:

```
func Testing(model string) {
    var temp interface{}
    if model == "UserDetail" {
        fmt.Println("Enterr...")
        temp = &UserDetail{}
    }
    u := temp.(*UserDetail)
    u.FirstName = "Dev"
    u.Email = "dev@gmail.com"
    //temp = u
    fmt.Println(temp) // {"", "", "", 0, 0}
}
```

**Edit**

Since your motvation is `The objective is that users would define their own structs and call a function similar to the Testing and I would get the data from the correct table in a database and then return the interface filled with data`, use this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type UserDetail struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    Email     string
    User      int
    ReportsTo int
}

type Matter struct {
    ID        int
    Name      string
    Active    bool
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    UserID    int
}

func Testing(model string) interface{} {
    var temp interface{}
    if model == "UserDetail" {
        fmt.Println("Enter for UserDetail...")

        temp = &UserDetail{
            FirstName: "Dev",
            Email: "dev@gmail.com",
        }
    } else if model == "Matter" {
        fmt.Println("Enter for Matter...")

        temp = &Matter{
            Name: "Joe",
            Active: true,
            CreatedAt: time.Now(),
        }
    }

    return temp
}

func main() {
    var temp interface{}
    temp = Testing("UserDetail")
    fmt.Println(temp) // {"Dev", "", "dev@gmail.com", 0, 0}

    temp = Testing("Matter")
    fmt.Println(temp) // {0, "Joe", true, current timestamp, default timestamp, 0}
}
```

Comment: The real problem is still present here. You are not using the `u := temp.(*UserDetail)` line inside the `if` block and hence I cant make it happen irrespective of the struct type.

Comment: Initially, I thought of writing code within the if/ else-if  blocks. But in reality, there are many lines of code which is common and if we start copying the same code in the blocks, it will not be a good coding practice.

Comment: But you can only call a common method of your structs (for whice you are using interface) using the interface, `temp.CommonMethod()`. You can't access the field of a struct (even if if it is common field) using the interface, `temp.CommonField`. The last attempt will give you error that you got before. Seem make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute type specific code, I would change the parameter of Testing function to (model interface{}) Then create a switch statement like:

```
switch model.(type) {
case UserDetail:
      <code>
case Matter:
      <code>
}
```